# How to bind numpad to tag switcher in awesome WM?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, awesome-wm

Under awesome WM, I found `Mod4 + numpad <1-9>` does not work as same as `Mod4 + 1-9` even though the `NumLock` is on. I think it's convenient to use `Mod4 + numpad <1-9>` to switch between tags. How to bind this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the numpad key map by using `xev`. So, it may be easy to map numpad to tag switcher as the following:

```
-- Numpad: [0-9] = [#90, #87-#89, #83-#85, #79-#81]
local np_map = { 87, 88, 89, 83, 84, 85, 79, 80, 81 }
for i = 1, keynumber do
   globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(
      globalkeys,
      awful.key({ modkey }, "#" .. np_map[i],
        function ()
           local screen = mouse.screen
           if tags[screen][i] then
              awful.tag.viewonly(tags[screen][i])
           end
        end),
      awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "#" .. np_map[i],
        function ()
           local screen = mouse.screen
           if tags[screen][i] then
              awful.tag.viewtoggle(tags[screen][i])
           end
        end),
      awful.key({ modkey, "Shift" }, "#" .. np_map[i],
        function ()
           if client.focus and tags[client.focus.screen][i] then
              awful.client.movetotag(tags[client.focus.screen][i])
           end
        end),
      awful.key({ modkey, "Control", "Shift" }, "#" .. np_map[i],
        function ()
           if client.focus and tags[client.focus.screen][i] then
              awful.client.toggletag(tags[client.focus.screen][i])
           end
        end))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keygroup` argument to `awful.key`

```
    awful.key {
        modifiers   = { modkey },
        keygroup    = "numpad",
        description = "only view tag",
        group       = "tag",
        on_press    = function (index)
            local screen = awful.screen.focused()
            local tag = screen.tags[index]
            if tag then
                tag:view_only()
            end
        end,
    },
```

see https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/input_handling/awful.key.html#keygroups

I am using it for tag switching without modkey, as I do not have use for the numpad otherwise.